# Using Django template functions in App Engine scripts

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

I want to use Django's `slugify` template function in my GAE script. When I use it in a HTML template, it works fine. But when trying the following import:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
```

got this error:

```
File "/home/karlis/bin/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in _import_settings
raise EnvironmentError, "Environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
EnvironmentError: Environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

For a temporary solution I just copied the function from django files to a local file, but the question remains: is it possible to use template functions like this and what should I put in the settings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work (without actually creating a settings module):

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
```